# Automatically have router send out IP Address

Tags: bash, shell, networking, nat

This is an interesting problem, and I'm not quite sure the right tags / context in which to ask.

Here is the core question: 
How can I automatically (& remotely) find out each time a routers public IP Address changes, and to what.

Background:
I have security cameras wired up in my house. I am able to remotely monitor the cameras from my cellphone / online. To do this I need the router's IP address. The router assigns a static private IP address to the Cameras such that all requests to port 8000 automatically get forwarded to the DVR / computer wired to the cameras.

- There will be times in which no one is in the house. Meaning that if the power goes out and there is a laptop that has a script running automatically sending the public IP address to an email, then there is no one to power it back on.
- The cameras seem to come back online just fine, I simply need to know the new IP address. The only time the router's IP address appears to be reassigned is during a power outage, but I could be wrong on this. It is infrequent.

So my question becomes, is it possible to run a daemon on the router that will automatically send its public email address out?

I want to be able to constantly have the correct information on my phone app such that I can monitor the house at all times without having to return home to monitor it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a dynamic DNS service? You will get a public hostname, which must be updated from your router to point to your current IP.
There are several free providers, e.g. [afraid.org](https://freedns.afraid.org/), which allows updating your public DNS record from various platforms as simple as regularly pointing wget to a specific URL.

Comment: Hmm okay. So somewhere in my router configuration settings I should be able to have it tell afraid.org (or wherever) what its new URL is since it is dynamic?

Comment: Depends on your router... Here is a [list](http://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/freedns.clients.php) of supported clients. Most routers should have support for some dynamic DNS providers, where DynDNS is probably still one of the most common (although they are not free anymore). Another alternative would be [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/free), but it probably makes most sense to check your router's configuration interface which DDNS provider it supports out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use a Dynamic DNS service like [DynDns](http://dyn.com/dns/)

Most commercial off the shelf routers support dyndns apis directly.  All you have to do is provide your credentials in your routers configs and it will automagically update the IP address for your specific domain.  Obviously this means you will have to acquire a domain name, but those are relatively cheap.

This type of set up will allow you to rely only on a domain name without having to worry about the public IP address of your home network.